# Easiest way to programmatically generate MDX rowcount query?

Tags: sql, mdx, olap

Right now I'm dealing with a program that can generate and return SQL or MDX queries (depending on the source database of the queries). I'm working on adding a feature that counts all the rows returned by a given query.

Now, I have some small background with SQL, so I was able to parse table names and generate a rowcount. However, MDX is a completely new beast for me.

In SQL, I'm creating:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(SUM)
AS ROWS
FROM
(
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE1
  UNION ALL
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE3
  ETC...
)
```

Now, what I'm wondering is, how would I do something similar with MDX? I've done some reading on MDX, and from what I gathered the basic notation is

```
[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level]
```

Now with SQL, I parsed the table names out of a larger generated query and simply inserted them into a new programmatically generated query. What would I have to grab from a larger MDX query to generate my own rowcounting query and sending it off to run? A simpler example of the MDX I'm dealing with would be:

```
 WITH
     MEMBER [BUSINESS1].[XQE_RS_CM1] AS '([BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[all])', SOLVE_ORDER = 8
     MEMBER [BUSINESS2].[XQE_RS_CM0] AS '([BUSINESS2].[all])', SOLVE_ORDER = 4
SELECT 
     NON EMPTY {[BUSINESS2].[ALL_TIME_H].[CALENDAR_YEAR_L].MEMBERS AS [XQE_SA1] , HEAD({[BUSINESS2].[XQE_RS_CM0]}, COUNT(HEAD([XQE_SA1]), INCLUDEEMPTY))} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_LEVEL,  PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON AXIS(0), 
     NON EMPTY {[BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[COMPANY_CD__L].MEMBERS AS [XQE_SA0] , HEAD({[BUSINESS1].[XQE_RS_CM1]}, COUNT(HEAD([XQE_SA0]), INCLUDEEMPTY))} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_LEVEL,  PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON AXIS(1), 
     NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Measures].[BUSINESS3]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_LEVEL,  PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON AXIS(2)
FROM 
    [SOURCE]  CELL PROPERTIES CELL_ORDINAL,  FORMAT_STRING,  VALUE
```

Any insight would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: wow - 3 axes is very rare! what is the tool that is consuming this data?

Comment: Buisiness Intelligence application. I'm working on developing an internal use tool to help analyze some of the queries being run.

Comment: I used to use Proclarity - now use Pyramid. Also use SSRS and Excel to consume `mdx`. I have never seen an outer query that uses AXIS(2). I have seen this in a sub-select but never in a main query. You are not really getting a flat table once this extra axis is used so "counting rows" is a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: I suppose you need to count the members of each axis and multiply these numbers together?

Comment: That might work. You're essentially suggesting I use .count on each member, then multiply the results, correct? I was aware I wasn't dealing with a flat table, which was part of the source of my confusion. Since you're the only one who responded, you want to format your comments as an answer and I'll give you a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance your script looks reasonable then after unravelling it becomes a bit(!) more complex.

The main difference between this and other scripts is its use of axis(2). In a sub-select extra dimensions are often used but this is a little odd as most clients can't handle 3 dimensional cellsets - so I'm intrigued by what is consuming this info?

Also the member `[BUSINESS1].[XQE_RS_CM1]` is a single member as is `[BUSINESS2].[XQE_RS_CM0]` so what is the point of the sections `HEAD...` ?

```
WITH
     MEMBER [BUSINESS1].[XQE_RS_CM1] AS 
         ([BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[all]), SOLVE_ORDER = 8
     MEMBER [BUSINESS2].[XQE_RS_CM0] AS 
         ([BUSINESS2].[all]), SOLVE_ORDER = 4
SELECT 
     NON EMPTY 
         {[BUSINESS2].[ALL_TIME_H].[CALENDAR_YEAR_L].MEMBERS AS [XQE_SA1] 
         ,HEAD(
            {[BUSINESS2].[XQE_RS_CM0]}, 
            COUNT(
              HEAD([XQE_SA1])
             ,INCLUDEEMPTY
            )
          )}
     ON AXIS(0), 
     NON EMPTY 
         {[BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[COMPANY_CD__L].MEMBERS AS [XQE_SA0] 
         ,HEAD(
            {[BUSINESS1].[XQE_RS_CM1]}, 
            COUNT(
              HEAD([XQE_SA0])
             ,INCLUDEEMPTY
            )
          )}
     ON AXIS(1), 
     NON EMPTY 
        {
          [Measures].[Measures].[BUSINESS3]
        } 
     ON AXIS(2)
FROM 
    [SOURCE]
```

Does the following return the same data as the original script?

```
SELECT 
     NON EMPTY 
         {
          [BUSINESS2].[ALL_TIME_H].[CALENDAR_YEAR_L].MEMBERS 
         ,[BUSINESS2].[all]
         }
     ON 0, 
     NON EMPTY 
         {
          [BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[COMPANY_CD__L].MEMBERS
         ,[BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[all]
         }
     ON 1
FROM  [SOURCE]
WHERE [Measures].[Measures].[BUSINESS3];
```

All you need to calculate then is the count of members returned in the following set on the rows:

```
{
  [BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[COMPANY_CD__L].MEMBERS
 ,[BUSINESS1].[COMPANY_H].[all]
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that cleared up a lot. Thanks for taking the time. As for your question about the HEAD, the MDX is generated from a simple expression, so it won't always be completely logical.